# How to reduce the line-height of a 2 line menu item with CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, menuitem

I'm working within Wordpress and trying to adjust the line-height of the 2nd line of text in a menu button.

The website is: http://www.rochesterevents.com/
On the left menu, I would like to close the space between the menu item "Lilac Festival" and the dates below it so that they read more as one event. On hover you'll see they turn pink. I tried adding the code below to the Custom CSS in the Theme Options but did not see a change.

```
.menu-item-10 {
   line-height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: An alternative approach: use top and bottom paddings to achieve the desired spacing on the top and bottom of each menu item, and use line-height for determining the height of each lines.

Comment: I'm currently seeing two `<br>` tags between the menu item and the dates. Maybe remove those? I'm not sure how the menu is being handled in the back-end.

Answer (score 1):

Creating space between such items with `line-height` is a bad approach.

Instead, consider creating vertical space between the menu items with `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` on the links (`<a>` elements) in the menu. Or on the the list items (`<li>` elements), if you prefer that.

This way, you'll be able to use `line-height` the way it is *meant* to.

Suggested implementation in your case:

```
ul#side-nav > li > a, 
ul#side-nav-toggle > li > a {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I would do:

Comment: .menu-item-10 a {
       padding-topt: 50%;
    }

Comment: Something like that. Personally, I'd probably use something like this: `ul#side-nav > li > a { padding: 1em 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the line-height rule on the a within the li as so:

```
.menu-item-10 a {
   line-height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is that the `<a>` tag *inside* the `.menu-item-10` one has its own line-height set (at 36px). Try this:

`.menu-item-10 > a { line-height: 18px; }`

Comment: Thanks Jack, it seems still unmoved?

Comment: Ah. The problem is specificity - the theme's default styles are written in a very highly-specific way and that's overriding your edit. You'll have to make it more specific as well - try `ul#side-nav > li.menu-item-10 > a`.